# how to change height of window title bar in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

there some applications with larger window title bars than in "Interface Builder". for example "Things" application. So how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the height of an NSWindow titlebar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639207/how-to-change-the-height-of-an-nswindow-titlebar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [following method of NSWindow](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW22) lets you modify the size of the window's content border:

```
- (void)setContentBorderThickness:(CGFloat)thickness forEdge:(NSRectEdge)edge
```

Comment: That seems to be incorrect. From the NSWindow reference for this method, "In a non-textured window calling setContentBorderThickness:forEdge: passing NSMaxYEdge will raise an exception. It is only valid to set the content border thickness of the top edge in a textured window."

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Not incorrect. Only the example given is an app window that is not textured. By my Things copy also seems to have standard title bar height. I was under the assumption that the question was referring to (non-textured) UIs like Twitter for Mac or GitHub, but text does not say that.

Answer (score 1):

Interface Builder and Things have the same size title bars for their main windows. Interface Builder does offer a toolbar, which when expanded can make it appear larger than Things.

Interface Builder also has a few NSPanels (I'm guessing this is what you're talking about). NSPanel will have a small title bar as seen in the IB Library/Inspector. These window will hide when the application isn't the active application. However non-NSPanel NSWindows will have the title bar seen in Things.

If you want normal title bars, use NSWindows, not NSPanels, but also note their [expected usage](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TPXREF48)